# Unable to install Hibernate plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Indigo. When I try to contact http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ Installing updates result in an endless ...pending...

What is going wrong here? I thought it would be the firewall. Turned it off, no succes. Tried reading all the articles about this problem, could not find my solution there as well.

Hopefully someone can pinpoint me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you install other features?

Comment: no i am unable to insatll anything

Comment: And if you're using "Install New Software...", do you see the dialog? Can you select an update site when the "Work with..." Combo?

Comment: i have tried but after i select items to install it keeps on checking requirement and preferences for ulimited time

Comment: That looks like your Eclipse can retrieve the p2 meta data, but not the artifacts themselves. Sorry, I don't have a solution to this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though less convenient, as the update site notes:

> You can also download JBoss Tools as individual zips for offline installation. See [JBoss Tools Downloads](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download).

You might also try using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or some other traffic analyzer to see where in the process things are hanging.  If it's just one bad repo, you might be able to route around it.  There might be a way to get Eclipse to give you more logging to get the same information, but I don't know how offhand.

Comment: hey I cant find the hibernate tool .zip file in the JBOSS Tool link provided

Comment: The link in your post has [org.jboss.tools.maven.hibernate.feature](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.3.0.M5.core/features/org.jboss.tools.maven.hibernate.feature_1.3.0.v20111209-0524-H40-M5.jar) and [org.hibernate.eclipse.feature](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.3.0.M5.core/features/org.hibernate.eclipse.feature_3.4.0.v20111213-1944-H40-M5.jar), is one of those what you're looking for?

Comment: but these are the jar file not the zip files.....I need to install them manually so I need zip file

Comment: [A p2 repo (update site) bundle of all JBoss Tools - Core plugins for Eclipse 3.7.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossTools/JBossTools3.3.0.x/jbosstools-3.3.0.M5.aggregate-Update-2011-12-14_19-42-13-H61.zip).

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are behind a firewall.  Make sure that you temporarily disable all firewall software and anti-virus software before running the update.

If you are behind a corporate firewall, you must configure your proxies correctly in Preferences -> General -> Network Connections.

Another possibility is that there is something wrong with your installation.  Just to be certain, I'd recommend that you delete your old installation and start with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If update site is not working for you (may be firewall or network issue), you can download the zip package from below URL. And go to Help->Install new software, click Add then Archive and select the zip files, note it also works for jar files.

http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/dev.html